# Specifying File Names for Pasted data in VBA...showing which file data came from

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working on a Macro that will take data from 6 different files and then paste that data into a Master file on top of eachother to have them all in one consolidated file.

I have written this code but now want to add to it. I am trying to add a column to the left of where all my data is pasted that specifies which file that data came from so we can run pivot tables off the master file.

For example, if File A had 1000 rows of data, I would want column A to have the value "A" for every row associated with data from File A. if file B had 2000 rows of data, then for all those rows show "b" for all 2000 rows and the first 1000 rows would have "a".....

my challenge in inputting values would also be that this is a dynamic range, so it wont be a standard number of rows each time.

Below is the code I have written thus far to pull the information I need from the seperate files and copy and paste to the Master.

```
Sub MasterFile_Consolidate()

Dim LastRow As Long



MsgBox "This will take a few moments"

'Open MF
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\zk4h90v\Desktop\MasterFile.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False
    Worksheets("2019").Range("B4:BO65536").Clear

'Admin
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\zk4h90v\Desktop\Radley Files\Admin.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Password:="VWMTA2019!"
    Worksheets("Resource Plan").Activate
    On Error Resume Next
     Worksheets("Resource Plan").ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
    Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False


LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Workbooks("Admin.xlsm").Worksheets("Resource Plan").Range("A4:BO" & LastRow).Copy

Workbooks("MasterFile").Activate
Workbooks("MasterFile").Worksheets("2019").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks("Admin.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False

'Blas
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\zk4h90v\Desktop\Radley Files\Blas.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Password:="vklf_blas4"
    Worksheets("Resource Plan").Activate
    On Error Resume Next
     Worksheets("Resource Plan").ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
    Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False


LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Workbooks("Blas.xlsm").Worksheets("Resource Plan").Range("A4:BO" & LastRow).Copy



Workbooks("MasterFile").Activate
Workbooks("MasterFile").Worksheets("2019").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks("Blas.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False

'Epstein
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\zk4h90v\Desktop\Radley Files\Epstein.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Password:="ccce2019"
    Worksheets("Resource Plan").Activate
    On Error Resume Next
     Worksheets("Resource Plan").ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
    Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False

LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Workbooks("Epstein.xlsm").Worksheets("Resource Plan").Range("A4:BO" & LastRow).Copy


Workbooks("MasterFile").Activate
Workbooks("MasterFile").Worksheets("2019").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks("Epstein.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False

'Deir
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\zk4h90v\Desktop\Radley Files\Deir.xlsb", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Password:="GFCC2019rft"
    Worksheets("Resource Plan").Activate
    On Error Resume Next
     Worksheets("Resource Plan").ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
    Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False

LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Workbooks("Deir.xlsb").Worksheets("Resource Plan").Range("A4:BO" & LastRow).Copy


Workbooks("MasterFile").Activate
Workbooks("MasterFile").Worksheets("2019").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks("Deir.xlsb").Close SaveChanges:=False

'Palazzotto
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\zk4h90v\Desktop\Radley Files\Maria.xlsb", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Password:="DATA2019rft"
    Worksheets("Resource Plan").Activate
    On Error Resume Next
     Worksheets("Resource Plan").ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
    Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False

LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Workbooks("Maria.xlsb").Worksheets("Resource Plan").Range("A4:BO" & LastRow).Copy


Workbooks("MasterFile").Activate
Workbooks("MasterFile").Worksheets("2019").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks("Maria.xlsb").Close SaveChanges:=False

'Thummala
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\zk4h90v\Desktop\Radley Files\Mahesh.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Password:="eit19ccor"
    Worksheets("Resource Plan").Activate
    On Error Resume Next
     Worksheets("Resource Plan").ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
    Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False

LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Workbooks("Mahesh.xlsm").Worksheets("Resource Plan").Range("A4:BO" & LastRow).Copy


Workbooks("MasterFile").Activate
Workbooks("MasterFile").Worksheets("2019").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks("Mahesh.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False

MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

If I could include this line of code to be applicable to every workbook it would be a tremendous help! Thank you again, if I can specify anything further please let me know and I will comment immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would benefit from extracting the common parts into a stand-alone function which just fetches the data from each file.

Compiled but not tested:

```
Sub MasterFile_Consolidate()
    Const ROOT As String = "C:\Users\zk4h90v\Desktop\"
    Dim lastRow As Long, arrData, wbMaster As Workbook
    Dim shtMaster As Worksheet, arrPW, arrFiles, i as long

    MsgBox "This will take a few moments"

    'Open MF
    Set wbMaster = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=ROOT & "MasterFile.xlsm", _
                                  UpdateLinks:=False)

    Set shtMaster = wbMaster.Sheets("2019")
    shtMaster.Range("B4:BO65536").Clear

    arrFiles = Array("Admin.xlsm", "Blas.xlsm")'<< add the rest of your filenames here
    arrPW = Array("password1", "password2")'<< and the passwords here

    For i = lbound(arrFiles) to ubound(arrFiles) 

        arrData = FileData(ROOT & "Radley Files\" & arrFiles(i), arrPW(i)) '<< get the data from this file
        With shtMaster.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            .Resize(UBound(arrData, 1), UBound(arrData, 2)).Value = arrData '<< add the data
            .Offset(0, -1).Resize(UBound(arrData, 1), 1).Value = arrFiles(i) '<< add the filename
        End With

    Next i

    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub

'edited parameters...
Function FileData(fPath, PW)

    Dim wb As Workbook, sht As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, arrData

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fPath, UpdateLinks:=False, _
                            Password:=PW)
    Set sht = wb.Worksheets("Resource Plan")
    On Error Resume Next
    sht.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
    sht.Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    sht.Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False

    lastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    arrData = sht.Range(sht.Range("A4"), sht.Range("BO" & lastRow)) '<< get data as array
    wb.Close False

    FileData = arrData

End Function
```

Comment: Tim, thank you. This worked well...my only issue is that the workbooks I am opening are password protected. HOw can i insert the password so that it automatically opens all my files without having to input the password for each

Comment: Password for opening, or password-protected sheets?

Comment: Hi Tim, each of the files in my array (Admin, Blas, etc) are all password protected workbooks that all have different passwords....how can i include this into the code above so that they will open without me having to input the passwords for each workbook.....thank you again for your help

Comment: Is the password required to *open* the files, or are the worksheets protected with a password?

Comment: Hi Tim, sorry - the password is required to open the files. none of the worksheets are protected, just the whole file

Comment: Hi Tim, I am getting a Compile Error: ByRef argument type mismatch.....could you advise how to move forward? Thank you again for all your help

Comment: it looks like it is happening at this point:   arrData = FileData(ROOT & "Radley Files\" & arrFiles(i), arrPW(i)) '<< get the data from this file................happening at the arrPW(i))

Comment: See my edit above for the `FileData` function parameters

Comment: THANK YOU, this worked perfectly...Tim, you sir are a gentleman and a scholar. I cant thank you enough...have a great day